# Turning USB into a terminal

Tags: usb, c, serial-port, minicom

I have a hardware device that connects via USB without creating a specific /dev/something. It does change the time on /dev/ptmx and /dev/char but that's about it. All I know are the VID:PID of the device and the documentation says that the USB (should) act as a serial device at 921600 8N1. If I were able to connect I should be able to send simple text commands (SCSI) to it, like on a serial interface.

I'm pretty sure I can use libusd or libhid to connect to it, but it's time consuming writing communication code from scratch. Isn't there some linux trick to create a /dev/ttySomething so I can communicate with minicom or simple C programs ?

```
$ dmesg
usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=104d, idProduct=3001
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-2: Product: ESP301 Motion Control 
usb 1-2: Manufacturer: NEWPORT Corp.    
usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000000000

$ lsusb -v
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 104d:3001 Newport Corporation 
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               1.10
bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0         8
idVendor           0x104d Newport Corporation
idProduct          0x3001 
bcdDevice            1.01
iManufacturer           1 NEWPORT Corp.    
iProduct                2 ESP301 Motion Control 
iSerial                 3 0000000000000000
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
 bLength                 9
 bDescriptorType         2
 wTotalLength           39
 bNumInterfaces          1
 bConfigurationValue     2
 iConfiguration          0 
 bmAttributes         0xa0
 (Bus Powered)
 Remote Wakeup
 MaxPower              100mA
 Interface Descriptor:
 bLength                 9
 bDescriptorType         4
 bInterfaceNumber        0
 bAlternateSetting       0
 bNumEndpoints           3
 bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
 bInterfaceSubClass      0 
 bInterfaceProtocol      0 
 iInterface              0 
 Endpoint Descriptor:
  bLength                 7
  bDescriptorType         5
  bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
  bmAttributes            2
  Transfer Type            Bulk
  Synch Type               None
  Usage Type               Data
  wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
  bInterval               0
 Endpoint Descriptor:
  bLength                 7
  bDescriptorType         5
  bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
  bmAttributes            2
  Transfer Type            Bulk
  Synch Type               None
  Usage Type               Data
  wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
  bInterval               0
 Endpoint Descriptor:
  bLength                 7
  bDescriptorType         5
  bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
  bmAttributes            3
  Transfer Type            Interrupt
  Synch Type               None
  Usage Type               Data
  wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
  bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0001
Self Powered
```

Comment: If it should act as a serial device, it likely implements one of the standard USB classes. First step is to use `lsusb -v` etc. to find out if the descriptors say that it actually does, second step is to check `dmesg` after plugin to find out if the correct modules get loaded. Depending on the outcome, you know where the problem is (device providing non-standard descriptors, kernel modules not present etc.).

Comment: I added lsusb to my question

Comment: As you can see, it's a vendor specific class. So either there is a vendor specific way to switch the USB interface to a standard class (did you get any Windows programs for the device?), or you do have to implement the vendor specific protocol (whatever it is) yourself, via libusb or otherwise. In the current configuration, it's also not a HID device (though HID devices are not usually used for serial devices in the first place).

Comment: Googling finds [this manual](https://www.newport.com/medias/sys_master/images/images/hd1/hec/8797091332126/ESP301-Command-Interface-Manual.pdf) with a code example at the end, using `Newport.ESP301.CommandInterface.dll`, which seems to implement a virtual Windows COM-port. In your place I'd run this example in a VM and monitor USB traffic to see how the protocol works, and if it switches to a standard USB configuration first.

Comment: OK, thanks, I can use libusb or even more simply a direct physical serial cable on another port of the device; so I guess I was wrong that there was a simple linux way to turn a USB into a pseudo-serial terminal.

Comment: In principle, it's simple and all works out of the box; but it requires the vendor to use a standard USB class, which the vendor decided not to do ... so complain to the vendor (who will likely say "but we do give you the Windows drivers, what do you want with Linux?").

Comment: It's worse than that, they sold me the newer version which only has a .Net driver ! That's why I'm going back to the old one which at least has documentation...